# Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error and Running setup.py install for psycopg2-binary ... error - Flask

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, python-wheel

I am using Windows 10, using python 3.9 and trying to setup flask application for the first time, following these steps:

Run pip3 install -r requirements.txt in terminal window to make sure that all of the necessary Python packages (Flask and SQLAlchemy, for instance) are installed.

"set FLASK_APP=application.py" to set my environment variable FLASK_APP to be application.py. 
I also set the environment variable FLASK_DEBUG=1 for Flask’s debugger.
I set PostgresSQL "DATABASE_URL=my heroku database URI".

Then I ran "flask run" to start up Flask application.

By the way requirements.txt only contains Flask, Flask-Session, psycopg2-binary and SQLAlchemy text.

But everything else installed except psycopg2, it threw up these two errors below
First one is:
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2-binary
  Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: see image for more detailed error text

Second one is:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2-binary
Failed to build psycopg2-binary
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2-binary ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

I have followed other threads here I have tried running pip install psycopg2 and pip install psycopg2-binary etc., restarted my PC but still same problem. Please any help is appreciated.

[Error message text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ldp3.png)

Comment: You've forgotten to include important info. Please [edit] your question and add: OS version, Python version and full text of the error.

Comment: Once I had this issue in my Windows PC. All I had to do was install postgresql dev packages and include their folder path in system variables path.

Comment: @FábioCorreia I have done that already, could you add the steps or source let me double check

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this by installing visual c++ with Visual Studio and its build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16 and https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16.